# Как определить, что директория переименована?

Tags: c#

Есть необходимость в создании некого механизма обновления проекта. Для этих целей я хочу сделать следующую логику:

- Директория `A` и `B` (новая версия), обе на одном компьютере, сверяем их различия, создав некую "карту" различий.
- В карте прописывается путь, размер, хэш и некое действие.
- Действием является то, что надо сделать с этим файлом/директорией (переименовать, удалить, заменить, распаковать, дописать данные в файл и др.)
- Клиенту в итоге посылается сгенерированная "карта" и архив с измененными файлами.

То есть, если директория `A` содержит в себе

```
- FirstFolder
  - lib1.dll
  - lib2.dll
  - lib3.dll
- SecondFolder
  - SomeLib.dll
  - SomeData.db
```

а директория `B`

```
- FirstFolder
  - lib1.dll
  - lib2.dll
- SecondNewFolder
  - SomeLib.dll
```

то мы видим, что в `B` (новая версия) `SecondFolder` переименовалась в `SecondNewFolder` и из нее удалился файл `SomeData.db`, ну и также нет файла `lib3.dll` из `FirstFolder`. Грубо говоря, снимок ("карта") будет таким:

```
- delete "/FirstFolder/lib3.dll"
- rename "/SecondFolder" "/SecondNewFolder"
- delete "/SecondNewFolder/SomeData.db"
```

Собственно, теперь **вопрос**: Как определить, что директория `SecondFolder` была переименована, а не удалена?
Ведь если мы возьмем список всех файлов и директорий, и сверим по наличию, размеру, хэшу, то проверка не найдет директории, она переименованную будет считать за "новую", что приведет к ложному выводу, примерно такому:

```
- delete "/FirstFolder/lib3.dll"
- delete "/SecondFolder"
- create "/SecondNewFolder"
- unzip  "/SecondNewFolder.zip" "/SecondNewFolder"
```

А это в свою очередь приведет к повышению размера патча, лишним действиям, долгой установки и так далее, ведь каждая директория может весить по несколько гигабайт, ну и паковать те файлы, что уже есть на компьютере клиента без изменений, ну такое себе занятие.

<sup>p.s. Про `FileSystemWatcher` знаю, но он не подходит по одной простой причине - новая версия собирается несколькими людьми и долгое время, запускать некий процесс, который будет следить за всеми изменениями не очень целесобразно.</sup>

---

Дополнения:

- Эта утилита создается для игры Skyrim, которую развивают сообществом. Есть автор, который создал свою сборку, со своими модификациями, переводами и прочим. Люди в праве ставить сторонние моды, удалять лишнее и др. Цель - передать людям изменения автора, обновив "ядро", то есть то, что его, не затрагивая изменения пользователей (удалять папки и файлы, которых нет в оригинале нельзя).
- Разделить файлы на "пользовательские" и "оригинальные" увы, невозможно.
- Модификации могут быть разные, в их директориях может быть всего 2 файла, а может быть под несколько сотен мелких (текстуры, звуки и др.).
- В двух разных модах (директориях), могут быть повторяющиеся файлы.
- Почему бы не считать переименование "новым"? При установки модификации, ее название (и название директории) будет взято с архива, либо с сайта модификаций и иногда оно содержит много лишнего (прим: `8k Texture 2021_RU_89а770407р`). Бывает так, что не обращаешь на это внимание и отдаешь с такими названиями людям, а в один день хочешь привести все в порядок, переименовывая `8k Texture 2021_RU_89а770407р` в `8k Texture`. Да вот только 8к текстуры могут весить 5++ гб, и если программа будет считать это за "новое", то человеку придется качать патч размером в 5++гб, когда надо всего лишь переименовать директорию.

Comment: Я вот вижу сейчас, что вы выбрали какой-то неправильный путь установки обновлений.

Comment: @ArchDemon А какой, по-вашему, "правильный"? Паковать весь проект в архив (или нечто подобное) и клиенту постоянно качать 150гб?) Или паковать измененные директории и файлы (считать переименованное за новые), что будет весом ~1-2гб (когда из изменений файлов ну на 400мб). Так или иначе, нужен механизм определения различий, по которому уже создать сам патч.

Comment: нельзя сделать набор файлов с их хешами и сверять с файлами на сервере. А когда клиент будет иметь все нужные файлы, тогда пусть клиент и разбирается, как луше реорганизовать папки.

Comment: @tym32167 Моя цель - сделать полную копию одной директории в другой, со всеми изменениями (не затрагивая изменения пользователя). Скажем так, есть основная программа и для нее пишется куча "модулей", эти модули могу как я добавить (а-ля официальные), так и пользователь приложения. Сами модули могут изменяться (добавляться новые, удаляться старые, изменяться (перевод например),  и др.). Собственно, если делать список хешей, то это не избавит от переименований директорий ведь (мод может изменить название, а это = новое название директории).

Comment: вообще лушче бы разделять папки, которые вы синхронизируете и папки, которые юзер может менять как хочет. Но если вы себе хотите усложнить таки жизнь - почему бы не сохранять информацию от последней синхронизации. Вот вы крайний раз синзронизировались - созранили структуру ваших папок с хешами файлов куда то. На след раз вы её используете перед запросом к серверу, чтобы узнать разницу между последней синхронизацией и текущим состоянием. Но это реально путь в кроличью нору, я бы на вашем месте для пользовательских модов сделал бы отдельную папку и пусть юзер там меняет, что хочет.

Comment: @tym32167 А увы, я не могу. То приложение, под которое это все задумывается - игровой клиент (Skyrim), который сообщество модернизирует. Есть автор, который создал свою сборку модов, со своими модификациями, переводом и прочим. Вот для этой сборки делаю утилиту обновления. Соответственно каждый может настроить все под себя, как хочет. Моя цель - доставить до людей исправления, за которые отвечает автор (его сборка), не более). `созранили структуру ваших папок с хешами файлов` - а как это поможет определить переименование директории? Ведь внутри файлы тоже могут меняться, а это == новых хэш.

Comment: а зачем решать задачу переименования папки? Пусть у вас не будет вообще такой операции, но будет операция создания новой папки и переноса туда файлов.

Comment: @tym32167 При установки модификации, ей задается название архива (либо с сайта модов), иногда оно имеет много лишнего (прим: `8k Texture 2021_RU_89а770407р`). Название мода = название директории. Иногда, при создании сборки, эту лишнюю информацию можно пропустить (ибо, по сути, для игры без разницы как зовется директория мода). Со временем, наступает момент "чистки" и `8k Texture 2021_RU_89а770407р` переименовывается в `8k Texture`. Вот как бы простое действие, да только это приравнивается к "новой" директории, а вес пака 8к текстур ~5++гб, а надо лишь поменять название...

Comment: ну тогда вам надо иметь какое то критерие похожести папки, чтобы понять, было переименование или нет. Например, если у вас была папка, её не стало, но есть другая папка, в которою 99%  от файлов старой папки попало, то это явно переименование.

Comment: @tym32167 Думал об этом, да только как грамотно реализовать увы, пока идей нету. Да и ведь в теории может "ложное" срабатывание случиться, нет? Как бы не переименовать что-то другое случайно.

Comment: Может вам по пути гита + lfs пойти? Или взять готовую связку, или, как гит, трекать именно файлы + отдельно раскладку их по папкам - это решит проблему переименования

Comment: @PashaPash Вот да, нечто на подобии git мне очень подошло бы, ибо надо знать и что в простых текстовых файлах изменилось, и что нового добавлено из файлов, что переименовано и так далее. Только вот пока не понимаю как сам гит под капотом работает и как это реализовать в своем проекте)

Comment: Гит то не умеет замечать переименования, если ему явно об этом не сказать...

Comment: @4per хм, и то верно. Провел сейчас тест в гит той же студии, при переименовании она [считает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkEe9.png), что старое удалили и добавили новые файлы. Странно, думал гит следил за этим раньше. Хотя наверно путаю с файлами.

Comment: Предложу использовать git. При некоторой дисциплине, если все участники будут использовать команду `git mv` для переименования директории, это будет автоматически отслеживаться.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Цель - донести изменения до простого пользователя (патчи/фиксы). Сказать простым пользователям чтоб они работали с GIT, для получения обновлений, я думаю было бы весьма странно. Также, не очень хочется арендовать спец. место на сервере, чтоб туда помещать 200гб данных, то есть нужен механизм, который на компьютере автора сверит новую версию со старой, сделая файл различий (аналог `.diff`, к примеру), я зову его "картой", на основе этой карты запаковать все измененные файлы в архив, ну и карту с архивом отправлять клиенту для дальнейшей установки.

Comment: Я это вижу так. С гитом работает автор(ы). Когда он закончил работу, он делает git diff - получает "карту" изменений между началом и концом работы. Далее на основе этих изменений делаются обновления для пользователей. / Репозиторий git может быть локальным у автора. Для надёжности можно и на гитхабе хранить, при этом игнорить большие бинарные файлы, но структура папок и текстовые файлы будут под защитой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, если полный список файлов источника и получателя развернуть в сплошной список, то они все будут уникальные. У каждого уникальный хэш.

Файлы в сплошном списке можно сматчить по хешам+именам между источником и получателем. Далее, вы знаете пути к каждому файлу, можете создать карту, как они переместились, переместить их из одной папки в другую, создать недостающие папки, распаковать то что не хватает, удалить лишнее.

Из выше рассказанной операции можно и выследить переименование каталога, но вам необязательно это делать. Вы можете просто удалить пустые папки после того как разберетесь с файлами.

---

Написал небольшой сниппет для примера. Так как с диском работать вы умеете, я буду работать без диска. :)

Вот такая модель данных

```cs
public record FileNode
{
    public int Hash { get; init; }
    public string Path { get; init; }
}
```

Задача привести в порядок диск за минимальное число операций.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // то что у нас на диске
    HashSet<FileNode> target = new HashSet<FileNode>
    {
        new FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = "a" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = "d/o" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 2, Path = "b" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 3, Path = "a/c" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = "a/d" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 5, Path = "e" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 6, Path = "b/f" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = "b/a" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 2, Path = "b/b" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = "d" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = "a" }
    };

    // источник данных, то что должно быть
    HashSet<FileNode> source = new HashSet<FileNode>
    {
        new FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = "a" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 10, Path = "d/o" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 3, Path = "x/c" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = "x/d" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 5, Path = "e" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 6, Path = "b/f" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = "b/a" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 2, Path = "b/b" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = "b/d" },
        new FileNode { Hash = 8, Path = "g" }
    };


    Console.WriteLine("== target ==");
    Print(target);
    Console.WriteLine("== source ==");
    Print(source);

    // сам процесс здесь
    Merge(source, target);

    // и вот что получилось
    Console.WriteLine("== target ==");
    Print(target);

    // проверяем
    Console.WriteLine("== Checking integrity ==");
    Compare(source, target);

    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void Print(HashSet<FileNode> list)
{
    foreach (FileNode file in list)
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

private static void Compare(HashSet<FileNode> source, HashSet<FileNode> target)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Diff = {source.Except(target).Count() + target.Except(source).Count()}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

private static void Merge(HashSet<FileNode> source, HashSet<FileNode> target)
{
    Console.WriteLine("=== Merging ===");
    foreach (FileNode file in source)
    {
        if (target.Contains(file))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{file} is OK");
            continue;
        }
        FileNode oldFile = target.FirstOrDefault(x => file.Path == x.Path);
        if (oldFile != null)
        {
            Fetch(file, target);
            continue;
        }
        var locals = target.Where(x => file.Hash == x.Hash);
        FileNode local = locals.FirstOrDefault(x => !source.Contains(x)) ?? locals.FirstOrDefault();
        if (local != null)
        {
            if (!source.Contains(local))
                Move(local, file, target);
            else
                Copy(local, file, target);
        }
        else
            Download(file, target);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("=== Updating ===");
    foreach (FileNode file in target.Where(x => x.Path.StartsWith("updates")).ToArray())
        Update(file, target);
    Console.WriteLine("=== Cleaning up ===");
    foreach (FileNode file in target.Except(source))
        Delete(file, target);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

private static void Download(FileNode file, HashSet<FileNode> target)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {file}");
    if (!target.Add(file))
        throw new Exception($"File {file} already exists");
}

private static void Fetch(FileNode file, HashSet<FileNode> target)
{
    FileNode package = file with { Path = "updates/" + file.Path };
    Console.WriteLine($"Fetching {file} to {package}");
    if (!target.Add(package))
        throw new Exception($"File {file} already exists");
}

private static void Update(FileNode file, HashSet<FileNode> target)
{
    FileNode newFile = file with { Path = file.Path.Substring("updates/".Length) };
    FileNode oldFile = target.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Path == newFile.Path);
    Console.WriteLine($"Updating {oldFile} from {file}");
    Move(file, newFile, target, true);
    Delete(oldFile, target, true);
}

private static void Copy(FileNode file, FileNode copy, HashSet<FileNode> target)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Copying {file} from storage to '{copy.Path}'");

    if (!target.Add(copy))
        throw new Exception($"File {copy} already exists");
}

private static void Move(FileNode file, FileNode copy, HashSet<FileNode> target, bool silent = false)
{
    if (!silent)
        Console.WriteLine($"Moving {file} from storage to '{copy.Path}'");
    if (!target.Add(copy))
        throw new Exception($"File {copy} already exists");
    Delete(file, target, true);
}

private static void Delete(FileNode file, HashSet<FileNode> target, bool silent = false)
{
    if (!silent)
        Console.WriteLine($"Deleting {file}");
    if (!target.Remove(file))
        throw new Exception($"File {file} not found");
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
== target ==
FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = a }
FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = d/o }
FileNode { Hash = 2, Path = b }
FileNode { Hash = 3, Path = a/c }
FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = a/d }
FileNode { Hash = 5, Path = e }
FileNode { Hash = 6, Path = b/f }
FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = b/a }
FileNode { Hash = 2, Path = b/b }
FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = d }

== source ==
FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = a }
FileNode { Hash = 10, Path = d/o }
FileNode { Hash = 3, Path = x/c }
FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = x/d }
FileNode { Hash = 5, Path = e }
FileNode { Hash = 6, Path = b/f }
FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = b/a }
FileNode { Hash = 2, Path = b/b }
FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = b/d }
FileNode { Hash = 8, Path = g }

=== Merging ===
FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = a } is OK
Fetching FileNode { Hash = 10, Path = d/o } to FileNode { Hash = 10, Path = updates/d/o }
Moving FileNode { Hash = 3, Path = a/c } from storage to 'x/c'
Moving FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = a/d } from storage to 'x/d'
FileNode { Hash = 5, Path = e } is OK
FileNode { Hash = 6, Path = b/f } is OK
FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = b/a } is OK
FileNode { Hash = 2, Path = b/b } is OK
Moving FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = d } from storage to 'b/d'
Downloading FileNode { Hash = 8, Path = g }
=== Updating ===
Updating FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = d/o } from FileNode { Hash = 10, Path = updates/d/o }
=== Cleaning up ===
Deleting FileNode { Hash = 2, Path = b }

== target ==
FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = a }
FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = x/d }
FileNode { Hash = 4, Path = b/d }
FileNode { Hash = 5, Path = e }
FileNode { Hash = 6, Path = b/f }
FileNode { Hash = 1, Path = b/a }
FileNode { Hash = 2, Path = b/b }
FileNode { Hash = 8, Path = g }
FileNode { Hash = 3, Path = x/c }
FileNode { Hash = 10, Path = d/o }

== Checking integrity ==
Diff = 0

Done.
```

Обратите внимание, что есть файлы с одинаковым хэшом, но разными именами.

Я думаю, что реальное обновление файла на диске (распаковку) лучше начинать когда все остальные операции мержа завершены. Потому что обновление перезапишет возможно нужный где-то старый файл. Но закачку архива для обновления можно начинать сразу. Собственно, так и реализовал.

Я понимаю, что это не строгая логика. В условиях многопоточки многое может поменяться. Я просто хотел показать идею.

Еще можно написать работу с каталогами

```
var directories = target.Select(x => Path.GetDirectoryName(x)).Where(x => x.Length > 0).Distinct();
```

...но я не стал усложнять

Comment: То есть я правильно понял, что я создаю массив, где будет нечто на подобии `(12345678 "/SomeFile.txt" 87f86gg94g9 )` (размер, путь и название, хэш) у старой и новой версии клиента, потом сверяю по их уникальному хэшу путь, по пути переименовался или нет, так? Если да, то есть "НО": Несколько модов могут содержать одинаковые файлы (текстуры, звуки и др.), что в свою очередь приведет к ложным срабатываниям определения. Попробуете может набросать пример подобного?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если файлы могут быть неуникальные, то немного сложнее, да. Набросаю чуть позже, с телефона не очень удобно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ обновил ответ.

Comment: Проверил на тестовых файлах, вроде да, переименование директории успешно определяет, показывая, что файлы надо переместить, а не качать. Чет я сразу не додумался по хэшу и прочему искать файлы. Спасибо за идею.