# Помогите с написанием LINQ запроса

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Суть такова: есть папки в которых есть файлы, после манипуляций с ними путь к этим файлам записывается в БД (т.е в дальнейшем мне с ними никак взаимодействовать не надо). Мне надо проверить, есть ли уже в БД файлы, которые есть в конкретной директории. Я пытался вот так:

```
var except = concreteDirFiles.Except(allDbFiles);
```

`concreteDirFiles` - файлы из какой-то конкретной директории, а не из всех нужных (т.к может быть вложенность в директориях, а действия над файлами надо производить в соответствии с фильтром по дате и времени)

У меня стоит `System.Timers.Timer` и проверяет все папки на наличие новых файлов, в результате для папки mydir1 я получу `массив string[2]`, однако, если эти файлы уже есть в БД (допустим БД вернет мне `массив string[5]`), то код выше просто исключит их текущего контекста LINQ и вернет мне файлы из БД (с удаленным вхождением `string[2]`, получается, что код `Except` возвращает мне `string[3]`), которые потом другой код будет обрабатывать и так до бесконечности будет исключать вхождение, но возвращать по сути уже обработанные файлы.

Как правильно написать LINQ, чтобы пропускать уже существующие в бд файлы?

Используется EF Core 5.0.10.

Comment: Может, вместо таймера использовать `FileSystemWatcher`?

Comment: Что именно используется для работы с БД? ORM? Какая? Укажите точную версию!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет, к сожалению мне необходимо именно сделать сканирование. ORM EFCore (5.0.10)

Comment: `именно сделать сканирование` почему? Вы сканированием сильно нагружаете диск, как часто это происходит?

Comment: Возможно [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1333869/373567) будет интересно.

Comment: @aepot вот так захотелось директору, чтобы именно сканировалось. Сканирование будет происходить по таймеру, который задаст директор. Хочет чтобы можно было задавать в настройках путь, сканирование вложенности (да/нет), таймер

Comment: Быть может дирекстор не в курсе, что изменения в файловой системе можно отслеживать в режиме реального времени без сканирования? Расскажите ему об этом. Управление вложенностью от этого не пострадает.

Comment: @aepot, отписал ему, жду ответа. А на счет ```Вы сканированием сильно нагружаете диск``` - почему?

Comment: @AlAvenger потому что каждая дисковая операция - это дорого. Представьте, что у вас 1000 файлов в 10 папках. Если используется HDD, на создание списка уже уйдет около секунды. Секунда - это очень много. Получая сообщения от системы только об изменениях в каталоге, можно обрабатывать только эти изменения, а сканирование запускать только при старте сервера 1 раз.

Comment: [FileSystemWatcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @aepot говорит нужен сканер, но если в частоте скана указывать 0 - то реалтайм. Так что вопрос все еще актуален

Comment: Так ответ прост - разверните список файлов в линейный список, состоящий не из имен файлов, а из относительных путей. В базе тоже его храните. Не используйте дерево, это неудобно и сложно. Разворачивать список в дерево можно только для отображения в интерфейсе. Чуть выше я ссылку давал на недавний ответ. Он может избыточен для вас, но как алгоритмически работать с файлами там показано. При использовании линейного списка путей, у вас не будет рекурсии, как и проблемы, которая вызвала вопрос.

Comment: @aepot хорошо, спасибо

Comment: @AlAvenger может быть ваш директор сам не понимает чего хочет и под "сканированием" имеется ввиду сверка списка с БД!? Т.к. сканирование реалтайм - это бесконечный процесс, который просто не позволит работать накопителю данных эффективно, а слежение за изменениями - полупассивный процесс, который может вообще не трогать накопитель и почти никак не влиять на производительность. При этом, с точки зрения актуальности данных - наблюдение - куда достовернее. Вообще лучше следить, а сканирование осуществлять только при запуске, или при подключении накопителя.

Answer (score 2):

Если ваш "директор" ставит задачу слежения за файлами, дабы знать когда какой файл изменился, чтобы определить источник изменения - есть такая штука в Windows, как аудит:
ПКМ на диск/папку/файл -> свойства -> безопасность -> дополнительно -> аудит -> изменить -> добавить -> Пишите "`Все`" -> ОК -> можете проставить все галочки (хотя хватит и трансфер/создание/удаление) -> И снова ОК -> ОК .. ОК

Потом глобально включаете аудит:
В cmd команда "`secpol`" -> локальные политики -> политика аудита -> аудит доступа к объектам -> ставите галочки (или только одну на успех) -> применить

Запускаете журнал событий:
В cmd `eventvwr` -> журналы windows -> безопасность -> создать настраиваемое представление -> выставляете параметры:

```
Журналы событий - безопасность
Источники - Microsoft Windows security auditing.
Ключевые слова - Аудит отказа, Аудит успеха
Если компьютер в домене или есть доступ - можно указать сетевой 
 адрес компьютера на котором находятся файлы и выполняется аудит.
```

Сохраняете настраиваемое представление с новым именем - всё, теперь сама ОС следит за изменениями конкретных объектов без всяких сканирований сторонним софтом.
Единственное условие - всё это настраивать нужно на том компьютере - где физически находятся файлы, а смотреть уже можно с любого компа (в настраиваемом представлении указать адрес компа, с ходу может не получиться, т.к. безопасность винды, домены, рабочие группы, учётные записи, итд...).

Чтобы убрать отслеживание, так-же через свойства объекта: ПКМ -> свойства -> безопасность -> дополнительно -> аудит -> изменить -> удаляете правило.

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoft-365/compliance/export-view-audit-log-records?view=o365-worldwide
В статье описано как экспортировать данный журнал и открыть его в Excel. Можно написать батник и засунуть в планировщик чтобы он запускал экспорт и писал файл в отдельную папку, из которой уже читать всё это какой-нибудь утилитой, может даже вашей самописной, в принципе хоть в БД напрямую экспортируй, MSSQL точно такое поддерживает, главное чтобы таблица была, многие другие БД тоже на такое способны.

Если не нужно писать в БД (его роль уже будет играть журнал винды), то в .NET уже есть System.Diagnostics.EventLog, им и можете читать. Прибиндить вывод к формам или wpf за пару кликов - труда не составит.

В итоге хочу сказать: если это нужно для внутренних нужд организации, то лучше использовать уже готовые инструменты, любезно предоставленные самими мелкомягкими, конкретно для данной задачи, данный метод точно работает в Windows 7 - сам пользуюсь, должен работать начиная с Windows server 2003, и может уже и был в Windows XP или ещё раньше, т.к. вопрос информационной безопасности стоял уже очень давно в зарубежных компаниях. Поэтому зачем изобретать велосипед, когда можно настроить уже существующий вылизанный инструмент, которому лет 20. Единственный вопрос: как удобно показать эти данные (binding: forms-datagridview / wpf, да хоть в браузере), если нужно не только в журналах - export в БД через xml или System.Diagnostics.EventLog с реалтайм докидыванием записей в БД, а если приложение было остановлено - дополнительная таблица с последних записанным моментом времени чтобы читать историю System.Diagnostics.EventLog при запуске и фильтровать её. Это лучше чем долбаться с файлами и папками и жарить мозги в попытках продумать алгоритм чтобы узнать что изменилось когда программа была выключена.

Comment: Но мне необходимо не просто отслеживать изменения в директории, там чуть посложнее. Но в целом ответ хороший, частично решает проблему

Comment: Задача состоит в том, чтобы получить новые файлы сделанные другой программой, сгруппировать их по определенным критериям, отправить по апи контрагенту. Хочет и сканирование, и реалтайм (чтоб выбирать можно было)

Comment: @AlAvenger один только реалтаймом не обойтись, т.к. теоретически есть время когда файлы пишутся, а программа выключена, поэтому лучше читать журнал Если только "другая программа" - журнал будет фильтровать проще и параметр аудита установить только на создание файла, в каждом событии пишется путь к файлу процесса, который совершил изменения. Если "другая программа" и пользователи не будут двигать или переименовывать файлы - то с режимом чтения оффлайн (сканирование) - проблем не будет. ``FileSystemWatcher`` конечно лучше чем сканирование в лоб, но вам придётся делать и так и так, или журналы...

Comment: Ну сейчас у меня сканирование и реалтайм работают с бд, если файлы уже существуют в бд, то их не отправляем. Если есть файлы в директории, которые не записаны в бд - отправляем. Файлы никто переименовывать не будет т.к тогда они не отправятся по апи (там свои заморочки). В целом, файлы если уже  создались - их уже никто не будет трогать. Даже контент файла если изменить, то он не отправится по апи

Comment: @AlAvenger касательно вашего изначального вопроса - одним LINQ запросом тут не обойдёшься. Т.к. файлов может быть просто немеренно. Если кратко - варианта два, либо в лоб смотрите на время создания файла локально и ищите время создания последнего файла в БД (разумеется должен быть соответствующий столбец), но нужно учитывать что часы - не самая надёжная вещь, либо считаете хеш CRC32 по пути файла и сверяете с хешами путей в БД (разумеется для хешей должен быть столбец), если хеша нет - значит пути однозначно нет, если хеш есть - достаёте запись из БД и сверяете точнее. Where, Array, Contains..