# Сравнение двух директорий с последующим удалением несовпадений C#

Tags: c#

нашел то что мне нужно, но на пайтоне, а я из этого только циклы понимаю...
Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли тоже самое воспроизвести в C#?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1389623/468694

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import os

pl = Path(left_way) # left_way = r'D:\left' = 'D:\\left' 
pr = Path(right_way) 
difference = (set(map(lambda p: p.relative_to(pr), pr.rglob('*'))) - set(
    map(lambda p: p.relative_to(pl), pl.rglob('*')))) # pathlib сила!

if len(difference) > 0:
    print('\nContent to be deleted:\n')
    for a in difference:
        a2 = Path(pr, a)
        print('   ', a2)
     while True:
        copyornot = input('\nDelete? (Y/n):\n')
        if copyornot == 'Y':
            break
        elif copyornot == 'n':
            print('...')
            continue
        else:
            print('(Y/n)')
    
    for a in difference:
        a2 = Path(pr, a)
        if os.path.isfile(a2):
            os.remove(a2)
        if os.path.isdir(a2):
            shutil.rmtree(a2)
    print('\nFinish')
```

Comment: Что значит "Несовпадение"? Какие критерии этого совпадения? Нет файла в нужной папке, или файл имеет другое имя, что? Старайтесь добавлять в вопрос всю информацию, даже самую незначительную и может быть очевидную, ведь мы не знаем какую задачу вы решаете, что за проект, мы не сидим у вас за спиной и не видим код. Вот представьте, что вы к первому встречному на улице подошли просите у него помощь, мы сейчас это те самые встречные, и в ваших интереса пояснить нам максимально доходчиво то, что вы хотите.

Comment: Все очень подробно описано здесь,
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1388993/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-python/1389623#1389623
 ссылка прикреплена в описании темы.
Это то что мне нужно, но я не пойму как мне сделать это на C#

Comment: я уже умею получать список всех папок в дирректории, с путями, умею создавать удалять, файлы при помощи классов Directiry и DirectoryInfo. Но я не могу свзяать это все в кучу. Точное решение сделали как раз в теме по ссылке, но там на Пайтоне.

Comment: Есть жестко определенная дирректория на диске P выглядит например вот так : "P:\\2020Test\\a\\1"
И она не должна выглядеть иначе, только так. А пользователи начинают добавлять свои папки, переделывать пути зачем-то. И получается либо так "P:\\2020Test\\МОИ ЛЮБИМЫЕ ФАЙЛИКИ\\a\\1"
Либо так "P:\\2020Test\\2020Test\\a\\1" и еще много способов испортить всем жизнь и работу.

Comment: Задача, проверить эту дирректорию и привести ее к нужному виду. Самый простой способ, это убить ее при наличии любой хотя бы одной ошибки. И создать заново. Это я уже сделал. Программа работает. 
Но теперь я хочу попробовать вариант не убивания, а исправления. То есть проверка , сравнение с эталоном. и что совпадает с эталоном-остается, а что не совпадает то удаляется и пересоздается. То есть минимировать разрушения. И эта задача оказалась для меня сложной.

Comment: Если надо именно восстановить, то простой проверкой путей вы тут не обойдетесь, нужно конкретно знать что за файл, что с ним происходило и так далее, то есть, вам надо примерно [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1333869/220553), где вы получаете хэш файла, а затем на основе хэша и пути сверяете текущую директорию с эталонной, составляя нужную разницу (удален, новый, переименован, и так далее), а уже на основе этой разницы делаете нужные действия по восстановлению.

Comment: Или вот так например Если не норм, сохранить это дирректорию изменив корень. например
P:\\2020Test_OLD_HORRIBLE_DIRECTORY\\a\\1 
И создать новую правильную дирректорию с нуля. А потом файлы положить по своим местам, ориентируясь на содержащие папки. Если содержащая папка из правильных например файл лежит в \а\

то положить в аналогичную в новой дирректории. P:\2020Test\a\  но этот способ плох тем, что если найдутся две поддирректории с одинаковыми названиями то будет ошибка или файл положится в и туда и туда

Comment: Евгений, файлы это псд, видео, аудио, и прочие материалы для видеомонтажа. И они не уникальны. Желательно конечно сохранить, что можно сохранить. Но можно и удалить. Проблемы не в ценности файлов. Их можно скачать опять. Проблема в том что пользователи постоянно создают дирректорию неправильно. Их проекты потом не открываются, ругаются на отсуствие файлов. И обьяснять бесполезно. Уже даешь им готовый архив  пустых папок с правильным расположением, говоришь, на положи на диск P/
Они берут извлекают в папку с тем же именем и на диск кладут уже это "2020Test\\2020Test\\a\\1"